# Error installing Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2 with tools! Error code

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, installation

When trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2, I get the following error:

`Error installing Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2 with tools! Error code: -2068578303`

Does anyone know what this means?

Comment: Can you give us some more information. Like what you have found out from searching on this, or anything different that you may have been doing. Have you checked the installation log?

Answer (score 2):

Error code: -2068578303 translates into hex 0x84B40001 which corresponds to an error in the SQL Server setup command line.  You can likely find the answer to your problem at:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when installing from an ISO mounted as a DVD drive. When the same installation files are copied from the mounted image into a local folder, and setup is run from the local folder, the error no longer occurred.